# Updating a many to many join table using sequelize for nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a Products table and a Categories table. A single Product can have many Categories and a single Category can have many Products, therefore I have a ProductsCategories table to handle the many-to-many join.

In the example below, I'm trying to associate one of my products (that has an ID of 1) with 3 different categories (that have IDs of 1, 2, & 3). I know something is off in my code snippet below because I'm getting an ugly SQL error message indicating that I'm trying to insert an object into the ProductsCategories join table. I have no idea how to fix the snippet below or if I'm even on the right track here. The Sequelize documentation is pretty sparse for this kind of thing.

```
models.Product.find({ where: {id: 1} }).on('success', function(product) {
  models.Category.findAll({where: {id: [1,2,3]}}).on('success', function(category){
    product.setCategories([category]);
  });      
});
```

I'd really appreciate some help here, thanks. Also, I'm using Postgres, not sure if that matters.

Comment: One reason I am not a fan of database frameworks... this code does not seem like it would scale.  3 SQL statements for what could be done in 1, and passing every column of each table back and forth from the DB server to app server just to satisfy the ORM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`models.Category.findAll` returns an array. By doing `setCategories([category]);` you are wrapping that array in an array. Try changing it to `setCategories(category);` instead

Comment: Thank you so much Jan! I can't even tell you how much time I wasted trying to get to the bottom of this. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are close.  I had a similar issue with some of my code.  Try iterating over your found categories and then add them. I think this might do the trick.

```
models.Category.findAll({where: {id: [1,2,3]}}).on('success', function(category){
            for(var i=0; i<category.length; i++){
                product.setCategories([category[i]]);
            }
      });
```

Comment: Hey Rick, thank you for the response. I think what you did will definitely work but the solution above is a little cleaner. +1 either way

Comment: I don't think this works because each call to setCategories replaces the entire list of categories, or in other words, only the last category would win and be added.

Comment: This should be using `product.addCategories()` as that will properly append